# How to center absolute elements?

Tags: html, css

```html
<li style="height: 10px; font-size: 40px;">
    <span style="position: absolute;">40px</span>
</li>
```

How to center `<span>` vertically? It should work for any `height` and `font-size` of `<li>`.
Without using `display: flex` for `<li>`. Interesting how to solve this with styling `<span>`, is it possible?

Comment: the problem you'll have is span in absolute position has to be in an element relative. And this relative element has to have a size for the absolute to be positioned by transform translate. So either you can give a size ti the li, or you have another element inside the li which will give a size for the absolute span to be positioned.

Answer (score -1):

This should work

```
span {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  -webkit-transform: translate(0%, -50%);
  transform: translate(0%, -50%);
}

li{
   position:relative;
}
```

However, I'd suggest using `display:flex` for this kind of thing

Comment: Please don't use `<table>` for anything other than actual tables, unless you're building email layouts for ancient HTML parsers, there are far better options for building layouts.

Comment: @oleedd take a look to flexbox or grid